# Injected elements and jQuery scripts. How to make them work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In some event of my script, I execute:

```
$('#myDiv').load('externalelem.php');
```

But, as we all know, the new elements will not be affected by functions executed on page complete. Like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ttip').tooltip();
}
```

These new injected elements will not have tooltips. I have tried to:

- call tooltip() after load()
- call tooltip() inside "externalelem.php'

None have worked. There are plenty of scripts that are affected by this issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just recall your tootip function after the new elements have been added to the `DOM`:

```
$('#myDiv').load('externalelem.php', function() {
    $('.ttip').tooltip();
});
```

You can read more about using the optional callback handler here: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery delegate method! It's awesome for this!!